# RxJS Combining observables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, rxjs, observable

I have a little (or big) problem with combining observables. I'm implementing some kind of tags-input.

`this._allTags` are all available tags.

I have 4 streams:

```
  this._suggestions = new this.rx.Subject;
  this._searchText = new this.rx.Subject;
  this._selectedIndex = new this.rx.Subject;
  this._eventsStream = new this.rx.Subject;
```

Search method:

```
search(searchText) {
  this._searchText.onNext(searchText);
  this._selectedIndex.onNext(-1);
}
```

KeyDown method:

```
keyDown(event) {
  this._eventsStream.onNext(event);
}
```

searching logic:

```
  const partitionSearchText = this._searchText
    .partition((searchText) => !!searchText); //check if searchText is not empty

  //put filtered array to this._suggestions stream
  partitionSearchText[0]
    .subscribe((searchText) => this._suggestions.onNext(
        this._allTags.filter((item) => ~item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()))
      ));

   //put empty array to this._suggestions stream if there is no searchText
  partitionSearchText[1]
    .subscribe((searchText) => this._suggestions.onNext([]));
```

And I want to implement events. If there is a searchText and `keyDown` event, then I want to increment `this._selectedIndex`, but if `this._selectedIndex` will be same as `this._suggestions` length, then don't increment it.

This is so far what I implemented:

```
  const eventsWithSearchText = this._searchText
    .map((searchText) => !!searchText ? this._eventsStream : this.rx.Observable.empty())
    .switch()

  const keyDownEvents = eventsWithSearchText
    .filter((event) => event.keyCode === DOWN_KEY)

  keyDownEvents
    .subscribe((event) => event.preventDefault())

  const isNotLast = this._selectedIndex
    .combineLatest(this._suggestions, (index, sugg) => index !== sugg.length - 1);

  keyDownEvents
    .subscribe((item) => {
      this._selectedIndexValue++
      this._selectedIndex.onNext(this._selectedIndexValue);
    });
```

So, it's incrementing `this._selectedIndex` but not stopping when it's same as `this._suggestions` length.

Can you help?

https://plnkr.co/edit/eh21d0d8U0VIsUyCjlkJ?p=preview

Comment: Please, prepare a fiddle.

Comment: here it is: https://plnkr.co/edit/eh21d0d8U0VIsUyCjlkJ?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it! Here is the code:

```
  const eventsWithSearchText = this._searchText
    .map((searchText) => !!searchText ? this._eventsStream : this.rx.Observable.empty())
    .switch()

  const keyDownEvents = eventsWithSearchText
    .filter((event) => event.keyCode === DOWN_KEY)

  keyDownEvents
    .subscribe((event) => event.preventDefault())

  const keyUpEvents = eventsWithSearchText
    .filter((event) => event.keyCode === UP_KEY)

  keyUpEvents
    .subscribe((event) => event.preventDefault())

  const enterEvents = eventsWithSearchText
    .filter((event) => event.keyCode === ENTER_KEY)

  enterEvents
    .subscribe((event) => event.preventDefault())

  const isNotLast = this._selectedIndex
    .combineLatest(this._suggestions, (index, sugg) => index !== sugg.length - 1);

  const keyDownAndNotLast = keyDownEvents
    .map(() => +1)
    .withLatestFrom(isNotLast, (value, notLast) => notLast ? value : false)
    .filter((item) => item)

  const keyUpEventsAndNotFirst = keyUpEvents
    .map(() => -1)
    .withLatestFrom(this._selectedIndex, (value, index) => !!index ? value : false)
    .filter((item) => item)

  this.rx.Observable.merge(
    keyDownAndNotLast,
    keyUpEventsAndNotFirst,
    enterEvents
      .map(() => ({reset: true}))
    )
    .scan((acc, value) => value.reset ? -1 : acc + value, -1)
    .subscribe((item) => {
      this._selectedIndex.onNext(item);
    });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/soaChC?p=preview

Hope it'll help somebody.